# button_to not working as intended with glyphicon

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using a Bootstrap button to delete a blog post. The button is as follows:

```
<%= button_to "Delete it", post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg" %>
```

The button works fine. It is deleting the post as expected. But now I wanted to add a glyphicon to the button. So I searched on the net and found the following solution:

```
<%= button_to post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-lg" do %>
<span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete it
<% end %>
```

It now shows the glyphicon icon as expected. But now when I press the button, it first shows a dialog box "Are you sure?" (as expected), and when I press "Yes", it shows the same dialog box for the second time. Now when I press "Yes" for the second time, nothing happens. The post isn't deleted.

Can someone please help solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find that using `link_to` works better and accomplishes the same thing:

```
<%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete it'.html_safe, post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-lg' %>
```

Comment: That does work. But then the color of text with "link_to" is dark, while I want to use the white color text of "button_to". (I am talking about the color of the "Delete it" text. Can that be done with "link_to"?

Comment: Add some CSS to fix it.

Comment: Sorry but I am new to Rails. Could you tell me how that can be done?

Comment: Add a new class to your link called "white".  Add a CSS class: `.white {color: white;}`

Comment: I did that. It's not working. The color is still black.

Comment: I tried doing "background-color: white", and it changed to colour of the button, not the text. How do I change the text's color? Thanks! PS: Strangely all css commands other than "color" seem to be working.

Comment: You specify the foreground color with `color`. You probably have conflicting CSS that is setting the link to black. But this is getting off topic from your OP. You should open a separate question for the CSS if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I have added a new question regarding the css. Hope you can help there! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388584/css-color-not-working