# Why is CSS class being ignored?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `link_to` as shown below:

```
<td><%= link_to '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete it'.html_safe, post, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-lg white' %></td>
```

As you can see, I have added a class "white" to it. The purpose it to define a CSS to make the color of the text "Delete it" in the button white. The CSS is as follows:

```
.white {
    color: white;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The problem is that all options other than "color" work fine in the CSS. For e.g., in the above case, "background-color" is working fine, but "color" is not. The color of the text never changes (remains default - black).

I don't see where I am going wrong. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You do realize you are specifying the color for text to be black....

Comment: this kind of question would benefit from a fiddle.

Comment: @JTG Oops! A typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks as though you might be using Bootstrap. Did you load your custom CSS file after loading Bootstrap? For a quick fix, you could try:

```
.white { color: white !important; }
```

But it's hard to recommend that as a permanent solution, it's kind of a faux-pas.

To find out which CSS is actually giving the text it's colour, right click on it, inspect element (or whatever for your browser) and then check out the computed CSS as recommended above.

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap. And my custom CSS is loaded.

Comment: Wow! It did work. Can I not make it such that my custom CSS always overrides other CSS?

Answer (score 1):

While user3783614's answer is correct and the easiest way to implement this I wanted to answer your question in his comment.

Yes you can alter them directly to override bootstrap like you did

```
.white{
  color: white;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

but what you have to do is instead of `*= require bootstrap` in the `application.css` use css import feature on your custom css file. Like so

```
@import 'bootstrap';
.white{
  color: white;
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

This way you can make sure bootstrap is loaded first before overriding.

To truely make sure you can use a class like this

```
.btn.btn-danger.white{
  color: white;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Since `btn-danger` sets the color adding a new hierarchical level will ensure precedence.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bf216gao/)